# Update have list to reflect local working copy

Tags: linux, command-line, version-control, perforce

I deleted a large folder I no longer need from my local workspace, i.e.
`//binary_blobs/...`. Now Perforce (command line) is complaining about the
missing files, i.e.:

```
test.raw - submit change default to delete //binary_blobs/test.raw#1
```

My goal is to tell the remote server that I've locally deleted the files, and
that the server/depot copy should be left alone. Essentially, I want to update
the "have list" so that it knows I no longer possess this 200GB folder of binary
data. I ran `p4 flush //binary_blobs/...`, hoping it would resolve the issue,
but nope: p4 is still locally tracking these files.

So, I decide I'll just tell it to sync this folder at `#0` to remove the local
copies of the files via `p4 sync -f //binary_blobs/...#0`, but this fails too
due to:

```
//binary_blobs/test.raw#1 is opened for delete and can't be deleted
```

Argh! Looks like I have to revert my changes:

```
p4 revert //binary_blobs/...
```

Now it's RE-SYNCING all the data over the network again, which will takes days.

## Question

Can I tell Perforce, via the command line, to just update the "have list" based
on what I locally possess, without re-pulling the entire depot from the remote
server?

Comment: It seems that you should have delete them using `p4 delete` and then submit your work....

Comment: @Hackerman My intent is to clean up my local working copy, and not to propagate these changes to the remote depot and other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out. First, I revert while keeping the workspace files as-is:

```
p4 revert -k //binary_blobs/...
```

Now I can update to revision `#0`:

```
p4 sync -f //binary_blobs/...#0
```

Saved me from having to manually re-create my workspace.

Comment: Have you removed that part of the depot from your client spec? If not, the next time you do a plain old 'p4 sync', the server will send you the head revision of those files again. So if you really don't want those files to be on your workstation, the client spec's "View:" field needs to be updated.

Comment: @BryanPendleton I did. Thanks for the heads-up.